# Total transaction fee for Paypal Chained Payments

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am collecting money from my customers (sender) using Chained Payments and divvying up the funds between the primary and secondary receivers. The primary and secondary receivers can have different primary currencies.

I need the sender to pay all the transaction fees associated with the transaction.
So if primary receiver needs $10 and secondary $10 after transaction is complete, 
I have to make sure I charge the sender $20 + total transaction fee

I am trying to figure out what that total transaction fee is.

I am not sure why paypal does not do the calculation for me. It looks like they support the calculation for parallel payments:

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay \
  -s \
  --insecure \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: caller_1312486258_biz_api1.gmail.com" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 1312486294" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AbtI7HV1xB428VygBUcIhARzxch4AL65.T18CTeylixNNxDZUu0iO87e" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" \
  -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" \
  -d '{
      "actionType":"PAY",
      "currencyCode":"CAD",
      "feesPayer": "SENDER",

      "receiverList":{
          "receiver":[
          {
              "amount":"10.00",
              "email":"mayur-facilitator@simplycompete.com"
          }
          ]
      },
      "returnUrl":"<url>",
      "cancelUrl":"<url>",
      "requestEnvelope":{
          "errorLanguage":"en_US",
          "detailLevel":"ReturnAll"
      }
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the Sender to pay the fees for Chained Payment.

Read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).